# Wordpress custom post type advise

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I am currently developing a site in Wordpress and in need of some advice. I have a task that isn't overly complicated but I just can't fathom a 'clean' way of doing it. Maybe in my mind I'm over complicating things so just after some help if I can.

I have a customer who does photography at various venues. They'd like to have a list of venues, for example 'London'. If they go to the venues page there'll be a list of all the venues she's worked at so I'm thinking 'venues' is my custom post type. However, when she goes to a custom-post-type-single page, in this case, 'London', she'd like a bit about the venue and then four categories (which she can edit), which are seasons. You can then click a season, like summer and then it'll have a gallery of images taken in London and in summer. Originally I thought of doing try make the location the parent and then have sub-pages for the seasons but don't think Wordpress allows this...

Hopefully that makes sense?

Here is where I'm stuck. Should I create the custom post type called Venues, which then I list all the venues as normal, and then create a taxonomy of seasons (winter, autumn, spring, summer)? My only problem with that is taxonomies are like categories which is right, they are. BUT, I want to add custom text/images to the venue > season single page like a normal 'page' and not just have an archive page.

Hopefully that all makes sense and I've not over complicated it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I personally would do a custom post type for photographs, and custom taxonomies for venues and seasons (or probably a hierarchical taxonomy that used venue and season in one).

As for archives - archives.php (or archive-custompost.php) (or taxonomy-custom.php) are simply templates. You can add whatever you want to it. As for saving "page" data, you currently don't have the best options. There are several ways of doing it - and there are Taxonomy metadata plugins - but true Taxonomy metadata probably won't be around until WP 4.4 at earliest ( https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10142 )

You could also make a shortcode to pull all the content for the archives, and put that shortcode in the "Pages" that you make manually. As actual pages.

Comment: I could be incorrect but can't you create taxonomy that uses imagery?